# Is it true that if generators of group commute then group is abelian?

Tags: group-theory

Is it true that if generators of group commute then group is abelian ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Comment: (courtesy of the identity $[a,b^{-1}]=b^{-1}[b,a]b$ $\quad\ddot\smile$ ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be agroup with generating set $S$. Then every element of $G$ can be written as $g_1^{n_1}\cdot g_2^{n_2}\cdot\cdot\cdot g_k^{n_k}$ for some integers $n_1,...,n_k$ and some $g_1,...,g_k\in S$.

Now suppose $a,b\in G$, Then we can write $$a=g_1^{n_1}\cdot g_2^{n_2}\cdot\cdot\cdot g_k^{n_k}\text{ and }b=h_1^{m_1}\cdot h_2^{m_2}\cdot\cdot\cdot h_l^{m_l}$$ for some integers $n_1,...,n_k,m_1,...,m_l$ and some $g_1,...,g_k,h_1,...,h_l\in S$.

Since $gh=hg$ for all $g,h\in S$ we have, $$g^{-1}h^{-1}=h^{-1}g^{-1}\text{ and }g^rh^s=h^sg^r,\forall r,s\in\Bbb Z$$ So that, $$ab=\big(g_1^{n_1}\cdot g_2^{n_2}\cdot\cdot\cdot g_k^{n_k}\big)\big(h_1^{m_1}\cdot h_2^{m_2}\cdot\cdot\cdot h_l^{m_l}\big)$$$$=\big(h_1^{m_1}\cdot h_2^{m_2}\cdot\cdot\cdot h_l^{m_l}\big)\big(g_1^{n_1}\cdot g_2^{n_2}\cdot\cdot\cdot g_k^{n_k}\big)=ba.$$

Answer (score 0):

Every group element is a product of generators. Lets say $x=a_1\cdots a_m$ and $y=b_1\cdots b_n$, with $a_i,b_i$ not necessarily distinct generators. Then
$$xy = a_1\cdots a_mb_1\cdots b_n $$
$$= b_1a_1\cdots a_mb_2\cdots b_n$$
$$= b_1b_2a_1\cdots a_mb_3\cdots b_n$$
$$\cdots$$
$$=b_1\cdots b_na_1\cdots a_m$$
$$=yx$$
I'm sure you can see how to formalize this into an induction proof.

Comment: Thanks.i cannot upvote answer because i have < 15 points